# Killing Socat and restarting it via a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need a bash script which kills als SOCAT-Proccesses and restarts them again. I managed it via crontab after a reboot, but this produces too much downtime to reboot again after there are too many SOCAT-Proccesses.

I used

```
#!/bin/sh
        
killall socat &    
       
sleep 3s
                
socat UDP4-LISTEN:PORT,fork,su=nobody UDP6:[IPV6]:PORT & disown
socat TCP4-LISTEN:PORT2,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[IPV6]:PORT2 & disown

exit
```

Now I have the problem that the script

1. does not run completely in background
2. often stops after executing the first SOCAT-Command.

I also tried nohup, but it also does not run completely in background.

Comment: Why not run the entire script in the background?

Comment: @user000001 how?

Comment: Remove the `&` on your `killall socat` line.  When executing the script, put a `&` there.  Like: `./thescript.sh &`.

Comment: The first Socat call will for each connection produce a child process that will never terminate on its own because UDP does not close connections. Add total timeout option like -T 3600 !

Answer (score 1):

What exactly should instigate this script to run?
Do you want to run it periodically, manually or when `socat` fails?

We certainly should understand why `socat` is failing in the first place.
I think it would be a good idea to output some logging from your script and kill `socat` with `SIGKILL` (-9).

A starting point here:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.sh
#!/bin/sh

IPV6="::1"
PORT=10001
PORT2=10002

while [ true ]; do

    killall -9 socat 2> /dev/null

    socat -T3600 UDP4-LISTEN:$PORT,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody UDP6:[$IPV6]:$PORT &
    socat TCP4-LISTEN:$PORT2,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[$IPV6]:$PORT2 &

    # Wait for a request to run or you could wait for a fixed time here
    while [ ! -f /tmp/req_restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge ]; do
        sleep 3
    done
    rm -f /tmp/req_restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge

    printf "%s: Restarting IP address family bridge\n" "$(date '+%D %T')" >> /tmp/restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.log
    chmod 666 /tmp/restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.log

    # Avoid busy wait
    sleep 5

done

exit
```

You can run it at startup, for example, adding this line to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/usr/local/bin/restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.sh &
```

And request it to restart your `socat` bridges with:

```
$ touch /tmp/req_restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge
```

See the running log with:

```
$ cat /tmp/restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.log 
08/20/22 15:14:43: Restarting IP address family bridge
```

Test your socat bridges:

```
$ nc -6 -l ::1 10002        |   $ nc -4 127.0.0.1 10002 
Typed from IPv4 TCP client  |   Typed from IPv4 TCP client
```

Be careful `restart_ip_addr_fam_bridge.sh` here is running as root from `rc.local` script.

Probably this is not very desirable/safe depending on your application.

EDIT: Added timeout for socat UDP bridge as recommended by @dest-unreach.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in solving my Problem. 

My overall Problem with Socat is that it creates too many processes and finally fills the RAM of my Server…

Comment: The first Socat call will for each connection produce a child process that will never terminate on its own because UDP does not close connections. Add total timeout option like -T 3600 !

Comment: @dest-unreach, updated so nobody that could potentially copy that script will have this issue. Thanks!